# Understanding comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm working on an online class and one of the questions requires us to match the name based on the index in the list with the salary in a comprehension based on the key with the following list and dictionary:

```
d = {0:1000.0, 1:1200.50, 2:990}
names = ['Larry', 'Curly', 'Moe']
listdict2dict = { ... }
```

desired output:

```
{'Larry':1000.0,'Curly':1200.50,'Moe':990}
```

I have written the following:

```
{names[x]:y for x in range(len(names)) for y in d.values() if x == d.keys()}
```

which returns an empty set.

Can someone give me a hint or two (not code answer) how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `d.keys()` gives you a list of all keys in `d`. When you do `for x in names`, x is a specific key in `names` in each iteration of the for-loop. Therefore, `x` (always a string) is never a list of the keys in a dictionary (there exists no string `s` such that `s==L` for some list `L`). Since that if-condition always fails, you end up with an empty set

Comment: See edit to x, which is now an integer.

Comment: Still, an `int` will never be equal to a `list`, no matter what their values are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> {name: d[i] for i, name in enumerate(names)}
{'Larry': 1000.0, 'Moe': 990, 'Curly': 1200.5}
```

You shouldn't iterate over `d.values()` - just iterate over names with `enumerate` and use that index to get the salary in `d`.

**After your edit:**

Your comparison `x == d.keys()` still doesn't work. `x` is now an integer which doesn't make sense to compare to a list.

I think you are just overcomplicating it. Try to remember what types your variables are and if the comparison makes sense.